# i am stuck with a query not able to get proper output

Tags: sql, t-sql

```
select G.region as Region
    ,A.Name as AgencyName 
    ,A.AgencyId
    ,sum(L.LoanAmount) as LoanAmount
from dw.FFLoan L
inner join dw.dimborrower B on L.BorrowerId = B.BorrowerId 
inner join dw.DIMGeography G on G.GeographyId = B.GeographyId
inner join dw.DIMAgency A on A.AgencyId = L.Agency
group by G.region, A.Name, A.AgencyId
order by  Region, LoanAmount desc
```

i am not able to get output in like 
i first want first 5 east then 5 north and then south and then west.
i need output only 5 region of each top loan amount

thank you

Comment: Please provide sample input data and output desired for us to give appropriate solution

Comment: use window function (Row_Number) & CTE. I am trying something.

Comment: You gave to write 4 same Queries

Comment: Region AgencyName AgencyId LoanAmount
north   xyz              11                5300
north   fgh               51                4300
north   abc               1                2300
South   adf               34                7300
South   avdf              64                5300
South   dfdf              32                2300
East    aggf               96                7300
East   aassdf              74                6300

Comment: I have huge amount of data but i only need top 5 of each region, iam using row num plus rank but i dont know how to use exactly

Comment: pls take a look at answer given below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
;With CTE as
(
select  G.region as Region
        ,A.Name as AgencyName 
        ,A.AgencyId
        , sum(L.LoanAmount) as LoanAmount 
        ,Row_Number() over (Partition By G.region  order by sum(L.LoanAmount)  desc) as RNo
        from dw.FFLoan L

    inner join dw.dimborrower B on L.BorrowerId = B.BorrowerId 
    inner join dw.DIMGeography G on G.GeographyId = B.GeographyId
    inner join dw.DIMAgency A on A.AgencyId = L.Agency 
    group by G.region, A.Name, A.AgencyId


)
Select * from CTE 
where RNo <=5
order by LoanAmount desc
```

Comment: thanx for helping... it work but i also want to set loan amount in descending order

Comment: Pls try now, if answer is correct ,pls mark as useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the window function `row_number()`.  This orders rows within a group (say region) by another column (say `sum(LoanAmount)`).  You can use window functions with aggregation functions, so the query looks like:

```
select region, AgencyName, AgencyId, LoanAmount
from (select g.region, a.Name as AgencyName, a.AgencyId, sum(l.LoanAmount) as LoanAmount,
             Row_Number() over (Partition By G.region  order by sum(l.LoanAmount) desc) as seqnum
      from dw.FFLoan l inner join
           dw.dimborrower b
           on l.BorrowerId = b.BorrowerId inner join
           dw.DIMGeography g
           on G.GeographyId = b.GeographyId inner join
           dw.DIMAgency A
           on a.AgencyId = l.Agency 
      group by g.region, a.Name, a.AgencyId
     ) t
where seqnum = 1
order by region, LoanAmount desc;
```